# Unity2D tile mesh render is darker than source texture

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, wysiwyg, mesh, brightness

I am making a 2D tile-based game in Unity.

I have a tile mesh implemented roughly along the lines of [this wiki entry](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/MeshCreationGrid). Full source code is available at [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/zTNnFw4F). When I look at my graphic (image file) it is precisely the same color as I see in the [scene view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZGOW.png); however, when I start the game, the mesh is [darkened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVN2w.png). I notice that when I change the Ambient Light color, it does resolve the issue (sort of): it changes the brightness, but if I set it to pure white, then the colors are *too* bright (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So2kW.png)). Furthermore, when I have regular GameObjects (such as the brick you see in the [second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6baV.png)) they are not affected by this Light setting. I don't understand why the mesh is. Is there a prescribed way to make it totally WYSIWYG? The tileset I am using is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuEiC.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the shader on the material of the renderer to Unlit/Texture or Transparent/Unlit - if you need transparency.